# Getting NotImplementedError when running Scrapy tutorial

Tags: scrapy

I'm following the [tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#using-our-item) for Scrapy.

I used this code from the tutorial:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "quotes"

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2',
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

        def parse(self,response):
            page = response.url.split("/)[-2]")
            filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
            with open(filename,'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.body)
                self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

When I then run the command `scrapy crawl quotes` I get the following output:

```
2017-05-14 02:19:55 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.3 started (bot: tutorial)
2017-05-14 02:19:55 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial', 'NEWS
2017-05-14 02:19:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2017-05-14 02:19:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-05-14 02:19:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-05-14 02:19:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-05-14 02:19:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-05-14 02:19:55 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped
2017-05-14 02:19:55 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-05-14 02:19:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/ro
2017-05-14 02:19:55 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET htt
2017-05-14 02:19:55 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET htt
2017-05-14 02:19:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/pa
2017-05-14 02:19:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/pa
2017-05-14 02:19:56 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://quotes.tosc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mehmet\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 653, in _ru
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\mehmet\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 76, in par
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
2017-05-14 02:19:56 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://quotes.tosc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mehmet\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 653, in _ru
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\mehmet\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 76, in par
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
2017-05-14 02:19:56 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-05-14 02:19:56 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1121,
 'downloader/request_count': 5,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 5,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 6956,
 'downloader/response_count': 5,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 14, 0, 19, 56, 125822),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 6,
 'log_count/ERROR': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
 'spider_exceptions/NotImplementedError': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 14, 0, 19, 55, 659206)}
2017-05-14 02:19:56 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to include the name of the error you're getting from your output. I also fixed some of your code formatting; it looks like you missed the first two lines of the first block. Also, formatting code within sentences makes them easier to read since it can sometimes be hard to tell where the code starts/stops within a normal sentence.

Answer (score 1):

This error means you did not implement the `parse` function. But according to your post you did. So it could be an indentation error. Your code should be like that:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self,response):
        page = response.url.split("/)[-2]")
        filename = 'filename'
        with open(filename,'w+') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
            self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

I tested it and it works.

Comment: Yes I agree. When I type over the code in the tutorial PyCharm makes the def parse(self,response): line nested in def start_request(self):. The code has to be separate to actually work. When I am doing a copy paste of the tutorial site it indeed works. It is very sensitive to typo's. Guess I am learning it the hard way. :)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the line

```
page = response.url.split("/)[-2]")
```

be

```
page = response.url.split("/)[-1]")
```

as now it looks like you are selecting the word `page` and want a number ?